# how to enable the option "@ style" in the xml android

Tags: android, xml

why in android: I can not use themes like: `android:themes="@ style / theme. (...)`
when i put `android:themes=" "` options that appear to me are: (@ id | id + @ | @ android | @ drawable | layout @ | @ @ style string but does not appear. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theme you can apply on particular Activity or Whole Application so `android:themes` will be available while you are in **Manifest.xml** file

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.GreenDroid">

<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.GreenDroid">
```

Comment: I'm starting with greendroid and I am following the tutorial the author asks that in the manifest I put the following line: 'android:theme="@style/Theme.GreenDroid"' but when I type: 'android.theme = "@ style"' I get an error because there is no option to style me. how do I enable it?

Comment: In your Layoutfile you cant find that option. open your Manigfest and write the same thing, see i had updated answer.